# LibGDX Screens overlapping when changing screens

Tags: java, libgdx, screen, overlapping

Hi i'm kind of new to libGDX and I'm just creating a simple game app. I have a main menu screen and a level screen for my game. I have initialised the startup screen to the main menu. When i click the 'Play' button in the main menu screen, I want to switch the screen to the level select screen but what happens is that it does change the screen but the old one is rendering behind that as well. This is what is happening when i click the play button: http://prntscr.com/57teri

Game class:

```
public class BallJump extends Game {

MainMenu menu;
LevelSelect levelSelect;


@Override
public void create () {
    menu = new MainMenu(this);
    levelSelect = new LevelSelect(this);

    setScreen(menu);

}

@Override
public void render () {
    super.render();

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    super.resize(width, height);

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    super.dispose();


}


}
```

Main menu screen:

```
public class MainMenu implements Screen{

BallJump game;
Stage stage;
GameButton playButton, exitButton;
Texture title;
Sprite test;
SpriteBatch batch;
OrthographicCamera camera;

public MainMenu(BallJump game) { 
    this.game = game;
}



@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    System.out.println("main menu");

    stage.act();
    stage.draw();

    batch.begin();
    test.draw(batch);
    batch.end();


}

@Override
public void show() {
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    title = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/title.png"));
    test = new Sprite(title);


    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    stage = new Stage();

    test.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/7f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/1.75f);



    playButton = new GameButton("PLAY");
    playButton.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2.5f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
    playButton.setHeight(50f);
    playButton.setWidth(150f);
    playButton.addListener(new InputListener() {
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            game.setScreen(game.levelSelect);
            dispose();

                return true;
        }});

    stage.addActor(playButton);

    exitButton = new GameButton("EXIT");
    exitButton.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2.5f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/3);
    exitButton.setHeight(50f);
    exitButton.setWidth(150f);
    exitButton.addListener(new InputListener() {
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

                return true;
        }});

    stage.addActor(exitButton);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
}



@Override
public void hide() {


}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
     camera.viewportWidth = width;
     camera.viewportHeight = height;
     camera.update();

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
    stage.clear();
    stage.dispose();
    title.dispose();



}
```

Level select screen :

```
public class LevelSelect implements Screen{

BallJump game;
Stage stage;
TextButton l1, buttonExit;
Texture title;
Sprite test;
SpriteBatch batch;
OrthographicCamera camera;

public LevelSelect(BallJump game) { 
    this.game = game;
}





@Override
public void show() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    stage = new Stage();

    title = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/level_select.png"));
    test = new Sprite(title);
    test.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/7f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/1.75f);



    stage.addActor(l1);

}





@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    stage.act();
    stage.draw();

    batch.begin();
    test.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
    System.out.println("level select");

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `LevelSelect` screen needs to clear the buffer before drawing. If you don't do it, the last rendered frame from the Menu will always be on the buffer.

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
   Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
   Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

   ...
}
```

Comment: OMG, i don't know how i forgot that... I feel ashamed of myself, wasted 2 hours on trying to figure out why... thanks so much :D

Comment: @user3650664 just a little "trick" i use in my current project: I call `Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);` and `Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` in the `Game` class (in your case the `BallJump` class), rigth before calling `super.render(delta)`. So before the `Game` class calls `render(delta)` for the `Screen`, it clears everything.